# Low liquidity on superuser?

Tags: discussion

I am new on super user,I asked a question a little while ago,and it feels like the website has much lower liquidity than stackoverflow! which am a little active on.Is it always like that?

Comment: Both of your open questions got answers within an hour.  I don't see how that can be low activity.....don't shun good answers it makes look like you feel entitled to answers.  If a question isn't getting answers, that indicates a problem with the question, your job is to fix the question so answers can be submitted

Comment: @Ramhound,yeah you said it,within an hour.I normally get an answer within 3 minutes or less on SO.

Comment: So you are just feeling entitled....The fact you get an answer to the questions you have asked within an hour is actually really really good, most times, questions like you have asked are never answered..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "liquidity", you mean "activity", then yes, we do have fewer users here, so things don't move as fast. If you look at [the list of Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), you'll find that while Stack Overflow gets eight *thousand* questions per day, we only get about 160.

There's still [lots of great stuff](https://superuser.com/?tab=month) to be found here, though!

Answer (score -1):

You never came back to clarify what you meant by low liquidity but based on my understanding of the use of the term in other areas you're talking about an unfavorable balance of question activity vs answer/edit/voting/moderating activity. That's actually a good way to describe what I noticed as well.

When a site like this grows it will get more questions asked. It should also grow in the number of people willing to stick around to help answer questions though not necessarily at the same rate. As new people discover the site when it grows in content and search engine visibility it's mostly going to be people looking for help and not looking to help.

Something about superuser seems to follow the fate of other tech forums I've seen in the past. People come in looking for help, they stick around to learn more and help. Some of these people will lose their initial fascination with the site after they have learned enough for themselves that they'll contribute less and less. Some will stick around and be curmudgeons.

I asked a [similar question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11592/is-superuser-still-an-active-stack) to yours which led me here. My question was why so few of the first hundred or so new questions I looked at had low answer, vote and view counts.

While Ben N's first comment seems appropriate the next two were more of the curmudgeonly type. First someone assumes that I'm asking because I haven't received an answer in a short time and criticizing my question. The second criticizes questions that don't get answers in general when my question was about all activity not just answers. People just aren't contributing on that side of the equation as compared to other SE sites like StackOverflow which you mentioned.

I tend to agree with your observation but what the underlying question might be I don't have enough insight on this board to fully answer.

Comment: As Ben N has guessed,I meant activity.It is just a silly term from the trading world.Anyway,my question was simple and I asked it because I noticed a big difference in reaction towards a post regarding voting,commenting,answering and number of views...That;s it really!

Comment: So if few questions are getting answers, and those that do get surly treatment, why are people bothering to ask questions here?  The missing piece of your theory: All of the people asking questions are masochists.

Comment: People are not contributing answers, I have 360+ answers, 9 were submitted in May.