# Is superuser still an active stack?

Tags: discussion

Posted a question then looked at the last 100 questions posted. Not many views, hardly any votes and maybe 1 or 2 answers. What happened?

Comment: You expect an answer to your question in 2 hours? Hint: As it stands you question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't expect my question to be answered in 2 hours. I don't frequent superuser much but I was surprised to see so many questions with so little activity while I was here posting my own question.

Comment: If a question isn't getting an answer it means a problem with the question exists

Comment: Check out some statistics here: http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-oldest

Answer (score 0):

SuperUser gets a higher volume of questions than I'm used to seeing and that contributes why the front page looks vastly different than the SE site I mainly participate on.